# Python/numpy: all values in array up to x?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an ordered array like this: `numpy.array([1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 36, 66, 90, 121, 230, 333, 500])`

Suppose I want all values up to 60 (if 60 isn't in, i want to stop at the first value greater than 60), so I want `[1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 36, 66]`. If I use `numpy.where()` with <= 60, it stops before 66.

My solution

```
from numpy import *
x = array([1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 36, 66, 90, 121, 230, 333, 500])
print x[:where(x >= 60)[0][0]+1]
>>>[ 1  2  5 10 25 36 66]
```

Comment: please correct your question. you probably meant to search for 66 instead of 60.

Comment: it would have been better style to do "import numpy as np" rather than importing * - also maybe clearer to non-numpy users what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything special in numpy for this.

```
import numpy, bisect
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 36, 66, 90, 121, 230, 333, 500])
idx = bisect.bisect(a, 60)
print a[:idx]
```

Comment: this gives me `[ 1  2  5 10 25 36]`, stops before 60. i guess it's because i worded it out wrong before sorry.

Comment: Of course it stops before 60.  The number 60 isn't in that list.

Comment: And if you do a[:idx + 1], you will get the number after your cutoff to stay, as you indicated in one of your comments

Comment: If you want one more, then ... add one.

Comment: I would see some sense in using bisect only if you have a list instead of an array, so that you avoid using numpy completely. Instead, you you have a numpy array, you should use searchsorted.

Comment: Moreover, the OP was focusing on whether the border element was included or not. the answer is that you should use `bisect.bisect_right` if you want to include it, `bisect_left` if not. btw `bisect.bisect` is the same as `bisect_right`

Comment: The precision of answers reflects the precision of questions.

Comment: This is twice as slow as OP's `np.where`, you shouldn't be using non-numpy functions with numpy arrays in most cases.

Answer (score 10):

there is a specific numpy function to do this, `np.searchsorted`, which is much faster than bisect.

```
a=np.arange(1e7)
c=2e6
%timeit bisect.bisect(a,c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.6 us per loop
%timeit np.searchsorted(a,c)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.77 us per loop
```

More remarkably ,it has also a specific keyword `side` for including or not the last point:

```
In [23]: a[:a.searchsorted(66,side='right')]
Out[23]: array([ 1,  2,  5, 10, 25, 36, 66])

In [24]: a[:a.searchsorted(66,side='left')]
Out[24]: array([ 1,  2,  5, 10, 25, 36])
```

Comment: This is the proper answer.